# Android drawable tooltip arrow box

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I tried the below code to create a popup window with a tooltip-like arrow on top. picture attached.
But I am getting something different as a result.
popup inflater :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
              mypopupWindow = new PopupWindow(view,500, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);            
              mypopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
              mypopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v,-153,0);
```

popup layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_recta"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="text long text" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" >
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%" android:pivotY="50%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp" />
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:width="1dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="206dp" android:height="76dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"  android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">
        <rotate
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="-50%"
            android:pivotY="60%"
            android:toDegrees="35">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                <size
                    android:width="24dp"
                    android:height="24dp" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Expected image :
[image]

Output i am getting :
[image]

Please help me to create a box as in the expected image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that difficult, key points are three to make this `layer-list` `Drawable`:

- The tooltip (triangle) must be fixed size.
- The background must NOT be fixed size, since the content size is unknown.
- Adjust the margin and padding (inside the `Drawable`).

---

**1. Create the `layer-list` `Drawable`:**

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item                      //background part
        android:top="17dp">    //margin top, half of the 【rotated】 rectangle height

        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid 
                android:color="@color/purple_200" />

            <corners 
                android:radius="8dp" />

            <padding                    //important part
                android:top="17dp" />   //offset the margin top, shows up the tooltip perfectly

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item                       //tooltip part
        android:width="24dp"    //size must be fixed
        android:height="24dp"
        android:end="32dp"     //margin end (right)
        android:gravity="end"  //place wherever you want 
        android:top="-12dp">   //margin top, negative half of its height, display half of this rotated rectangle

        <rotate 
            android:fromDegrees="45">

            <shape 
                android:shape="rectangle">

                <solid 
                    android:color="@color/purple_500" />    //change back to background part color after your experiment and testing

            </shape>

        </rotate>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**2. Apply to `View`:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hi, I'm Sam"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_background"    //here
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"/>                //apply padding bottom in Drawable, not in here

<TextView                                             //just for comparison
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Hi, I'm Sam"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"/>
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Little Math:**

- Un-rotated rectangle height is `24dp`.
- Rotated rectangle height is `square root of (24^2)*2 = 33.9411`.
- Half of the Rotated rectangle height is `16.9706`, so we take `17`.

---

**Tips For applying vertical padding:**

- Modify the padding top of **Background part** (ex: `17dp + 8dp = 25dp`).
- Modify the margin top of **Tooltip (rotated rectangle) part** to cancel out (ex: `-12dp - 8dp = -20dp`).

Comment: This helped me to create an arrow as expected.But unable to draw the border blue color on top portions only.Any idea?

Comment: @Malhotra Easy.

Comment: This is perfect !

Answer (score 6):

This is your demand:

- Stroke style
- Show the arrow top portion only

---

**1. Change my example answer from solid color style to stroke style:**

- Apply to both **Background part** and the **Tooltip part**.

  ```
  <stroke
      android:color="@color/purple_200"
      android:width="2dp"/>    //border thickness, keep this in mind

  <solid
      android:color="@color/white" />    //white background color, must have
  ```
- Now you notice that the bottom half of the rotated rectangle is also shown up, how to hide it? Well, the idea is to make something to **Cover/Overlay** it - but not completely. We need one more layer.

**2. Duplicate the tooltip part to make it as the third layer, and all we need to do is just moving it down the distance of `border width + 1dp = 3dp`, and give it a solid white background color:**

```
<item
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:end="32dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:top="-9dp">    //here, -12 + 3 = -9

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">

        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid
                android:color="@color/purple_500" />    //change back to white after your testing

        </shape>

    </rotate>

</item>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Malhotra Does this help?

Comment: Thank you... This works like a charm for me. Can you please add the changes to show triangle at bottom, right and left ? I have tried changing gravity but did not worked.

Comment: @Bhavana Answer provided.

Answer (score 3):

For bottom:

[image]

---

For left:

[image]

("sp" was mistake, should use "dp" instead.)

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to make your example work for API level 21? I discovered that `android:width`, `android:height`, and `android:start` are only available since API level 23.